# Why can't a quarterstaff be made out of metal?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, weapons, designer-reasons, special-materials

Both Pathfinder and 3.5e have restrictions on the use of special materials in crafted weapons. For instance, by mithral and adamantine they both specify that items not made of metal (or not primarily of metal) do not gain any benefit from using these materials. Quarterstaffs in particular are called out as examples of this.

Is there an official explanation provided (by WotC, Paizo, Dragon magazine, etc.) for why couldn't you make a staff of metal? It's still an effective weapon, and one might argue it's even MORE effective than a similarly sized length of wood, without the danger of it splintering in combat!

**Speculation is never appropriate for an SE answer. Answers must have cited evidence demonstrating the publishers’ position**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [designer-reasons questions are no longer considered on-topic here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Nobody says they cant

But they are **usually made of wood**, as wood is much lighter than iron or steel. The [heaviest of woods](http://www.wood-database.com/wood-articles/top-ten-heaviest-woods/) are between 74.4 lbs/ft<sup>3</sup> to 84.5 lbs/ft<sup>3</sup>. While [iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron) has a density of 491.5 lbs/ft<sup>3</sup>, and [steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel) has a density of 483.81 lbs/ft<sup>3</sup> according to Wikipedia. Both are at least *six times heavier* for the same dimensions.

And evidence of that is the [Undine Weaponshaft](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Undine%20weaponshaft), which is a mundane enhancement that can be applied to metal quarterstaves, spears and tridents (normally made of wood), it even says they can be made of special metal materials (mithril and adamatine). At the end of [Ruby Phoenix Tournament module](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8qid), there is an npc with an [Adamantine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Adamantine) quarterstaff. At the [Council of Thieves adventure path](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventurePath/councilOfThieves), there is another npc with a *bonded item* that is a [Mithral](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral) quarterstaff. At the [Crucible of Chaos](http://paizo.com/products/btpy81qt?GameMastery-Module-J3-Crucible-of-Chaos) module (3.5) there is a magical staff, but this time made of [Mithral](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral).

According to the *core rulebook* on staves (the magical ones):

> A **typical** staff measures anywhere from 4 feet to 7 feet long and is 2 inches to 3 inches thick, weighing about 5 pounds. Most staves are wood, but an exotic few are bone, **metal**, or even glass.
>
> A typical staff is like a walking stick, **quarterstaff**, or cudgel.

So, your typical quarterstaff (4 lbs) would weight at least 6 times as much (24 lbs), but its not impossible to be crafted. And also note that this is twice the weight of the heaviest weapons in the core rulebook (greataxe, halberd, guisarme, etc), and as such, why would anyone carry one of those for 1d6 damage if they could deal twice as much damage with an overall better weapon.

So when we read the rules about [special materials](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/) saying a quarterstaff cannot be made of mithril/adamantine, it is talking about our *typical* quarterstaff.

> A longsword can be a mithral weapon, while a quarterstaff cannot.
>
> An arrow could be made of adamantine, but a quarterstaff could not.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60916/discussion-on-answer-by-shadowkras-why-cant-a-quarterstaff-be-made-out-of-metal).

Answer (score 10):

***Note:*** Another [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/101507/8610) address [pathfinder](/questions/tagged/pathfinder) *nonwooden quarterstaffs; this answer addresses* [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) *nonwooden quarterstaffs.*

---

### Only specific special materials and the *Dungeon Master's Guide*'s examples in [Special Materials](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#special-materials) prevent nonwooden quarterstaffs

The *Player's Handbook* doesn't mention that a quarterstaff must be made from wood in the [quarterstaff](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#quarterstaff) description (120).

Further investigation shows the following:

1. The 1st-level Drd spell [*shillelagh*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shillelagh) [trans] (*PH* 278) has the
   entry *Target: One touched nonmagical oak club or quarterstaff* and
   that entry *can* be read as necessitating specifically an *oak*
   quarterstaff therefore—obviously—prohibiting the spell *shillelagh*
   from being cast on a quarterstaff made from another material.
2. The 6th-level Drd spell [*spellstaff*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#spellstaff) [trans] (*PH* 282) has the
   entry *Target: Wooden quarterstaff touched* and repeats in its
   description the necessity of a *wooden* quarterstaff in which to
   store the accompanying spell.
3. The 7th-level druid spell [*changestaff*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#changestaff) [trans] (*PH* 208)
   mandates its focus be a quarterstaff that's made from "a sound limb
   cut from an ash, oak, or yew," so a quarterstaff of another material
   typically can't be used as focus for that spell, either.

   Yet all of these other quarterstaff descriptions beyond the initial description do *specify* wood as if other materials *were* options.

It's not until the *Dungeon Master's Guide* mentions that "[i]tems without metal parts cannot be made from [adamantine](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#adamantine)," and then goes on to explain how  "[a]n arrow could be made of adamantine, but a quarterstaff could not" (283) and repeating this exclusion in the description of [cold iron](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#cold-iron) (284). However, the description of [mithral](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#mithral), rather than specifically excluding the quarterstaff, instead excludes the scythe (*ibid.*), and the description of [alchemical silver](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#table-alchemical-silver-items) (284-5) provides no examples at all!

In addition, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on magic [Staffs](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsSSW.html#staffs) says that most "are wood, but a rare few are bone, metal, or even glass" (243), and among the necessary materials for creating a magic staff *is* a [masterwork quarterstaff](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#table-summary-of-magic-item-creation-costs) (284). How these "extremely exotic" magic staffs exist if a quarterstaff *can't* be made from nonwooden material is mystery.

Just in case, I checked out a couple of *other* special materials:

- **Abyssal bloodiron** (*Planar Handbook* 69) (also my stage name in my imaginary heavy metal band) places no restrictions on what can be made from it, although the material *is* limited to weapons.
- **Pandemonic silver** (*Complete Warrior* 136) (on guitar) "can be used to coat the striking surface of any slashing or piercing weapon made of steel," so it's that a quarterstaff deals bludgeoning damage is the problem with adding pandemonic silver to it *not* that the special material presupposes a wooden quarterstaff.
- **Rimefire ice** (*Frostburn* 80-1) (on bass) says that the material "can be used to create any weapon that is normally made out of wood (or nearly completely of wood, as in the case of a spear or javelin)," but the *Player's Handbook* descriptions of the javelin, longspear, shortspear, and spear (118, 119, 120, and 120 again, respectively) are silent as to those weapon's compositions, too!
- **Thinaun** (*Complete Warrior* 136-7) (on drums) says that "[o]nly melee weapons made primarily of metal can be crafted as thinaun weapons" yet offers no examples or restrictions.

In other words, a player that wants to, according to rules, have his PC employ a nonwooden quarterstaff is up against *only* the prejudices established by the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on adamatine and cold iron… and any restrictions placed on weapons by *other* specific special materials. Absent those examples—which, don't be mistaken, really *are* there—and such restrictions, the DM decides if a quarterstaff (or another weapon that game boldly presumes is primarily made of wood like a javelin or longspear) can be made from a nonwooden special material or even just normal ol' metal.

Keep in mind, though, that *this* DM would look askance at a player that claimed his PC's hey-it-was-free nonwooden quarterstaff were *more* durable than the typical quarterstaff! (According to magic staffs, that's hardness 5, hp 10, and break DC 24, equal to—surprise!—a two-handed hafted weapon like the greataxe (*PH* 158).) [Seriously](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#sunder).) This DM *would* make the PC pay *something* for increased durability, even were the player to claim his PC swiped the metal pole from a construction site or whatever.

Comment: A player who claims an iron quarterstaff should be free when a wooden one has no listed price actually deserved to be beaten by thugs wielding *metal* quarterstaffs.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Guilty as charged, Your Honor, I revised that to avoid the wrath of Sampson.

Answer (score 7):

**Volume of a quarterstaff**

A quarterstaff (assuming 2" thick and 7 feet tall) would have a volume of 0.15 cubic feet.  By comparison, the bo staff is about 1.25" thick, so we're in the right ballpark.

**What did other weapons weigh?**

A longsword weighs around 3 lbs. A bastard sword around 4.5 lbs.  An axe around 4 lbs.  A halberd comes in around 6 lbs.

**Material Densities**

- Oak - 47 lbs / ft<sup>3</sup>
- Iron - 491 lbs / ft<sup>3</sup>
- Mithril - 246 lbs / ft<sup>3</sup>
- Titanium - 280 lbs / ft<sup>3</sup>
- Aluminum - 170 lbs / ft<sup>3</sup>

**How much does our staff weigh?**

Oak (a good hardwood) has an average density of around 47 pounds per cubic foot.  That means our quarterstaff weighs around 7 lbs.

The lightest metal that could be useful for our purposes is aluminum.  The same staff weighs 25.5 lbs.

Mithril and titanium are close enough in density to be the same for these purposes.  We end up around 265 lbs per cubic foot, so about 40 lbs for our staff.

Iron is the heaviest metal, at 491 lbs per cubic foot (steel is about ~5 lbs lighter), so you end up with a 74 lb staff.

For comparison, the weightiest ordinary weapon we can find for a Medium creature is a Large maul employed 2-handed by someone with Exotic Weapon Proficiency (maul), if that's even allowed — that maul's weight is 40 lbs.

In short, unless you're REALLY strong, the metals are just too dense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60355/discussion-on-answer-by-helheimrpg-why-cant-a-quarterstaff-be-made-out-of-metal).

Comment: No really, moved to chat.

Comment: Why not a hollow metal staff, like an aluminum baseball bat?

Answer (score 1):

They can: Buy a Lantern Staff (Simple Weapon, 15 GP, 9 Lbs). It is a metal quarterstaff with a Hooded Lantern on one end. It is treated as a staff except that it can't be used as a double weapon - unless, I suppose, you take the lantern off the top (and probably save a pound). Of course, that will mean giving up the +1 point of fire damage.

But there you are; they're made of metal, they're generally treated as quarterstaves, and you can use quite a lot of special materials in them.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! I'm familiar with a lot of *D&D 3.5* weapons but not that one! Can this answer provide a source for the lantern staff? Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: It's in the ***Pathfinder Player Companion: Adventurer’s Armory 2***.  Please add page number if you have it and a short passage from that section of the book wouldn't hurt either. Answers should always be cited and especially so on this one since the OP specifically is requesting cited material.

Comment: He asked for "official explanation provided (by WotC, Paizo, Dragon magazine, etc.) for why couldn't you make a staff of metal". Since the online Pathfinder SRD indicates that you can, the answer is provided as the reason why there is no need to cite a nonexistent official source for why you can't,